# Is it okay when multiple DLLs loaded dynamically have functions with identical names?

Tags: c, dll

Please consider a C application which uses `LoadLibrary` to load several different DLLs during runtime, and uses `GetProcAddress(dll, "some_function_name")` to call each one's `some_function_name` function.

Is it okay if all of the DLLs have a function named `some_function_name`? Or is this prone to cause problems inside the process?

Also, is the answer different on the Linux equivalent?

Comment: Consider what would happen if it wasn't okay. Software developers all over the world would have to make sure their function names are globally unique.

Comment: Yes, it is ok to have functions have the same name even in different `.dll`s. You can differentiate them by the module they are loaded in. Multiple functions cannot have the same name inside a single `dll`, but a function name can be present in multiple `dll`s.

As for linux dynamic linked libraries, i have no clue.

Comment: It is definitely okay, and (to help you think about it a little differently) can be a useful pattern in practice.  For example, think of a program where (through configuration or some other mechanism) you register a number of DLL or so files, and the program uses the services in those libraries for different scenarios.  There is an expected protocol where the library defines a function of known name, e.g., "`event_handler`()", that the program dynamically loads and utilizes at run-time.